# Qualtrics generic survey link: How to prevent respondents from taking survey more than once without Qualtrics API

Tags: c#, asp.net, qualtrics

I'm working on a project where we have placed Qualtrics generic link on asp.net web page with embedded Qualtrics fields data passing as parameters from URL query string.

Once user clicks on link(Quatrics generic link with query string parameters) in web page, page will redirected to the Qualtrics survey page. From there whole application control goes to Qualtrics tool, where user can complete the survey or close the browser or they can resubmit the survey.

Asp .Net web page with URL : `https://qualtrics.com/<Survey_Name>?USER-ID=1234&USER_REF_NO=32320`

Qualtrics Embedded Fields: USER-ID and USER_REF_NO

We are able to get the responses and able to identify each response using embedded fields (USER-ID and USER_REF_NO), But we are not able to restrict the user to take survey only once, because of this we are ending up with duplicate records, it's consuming lot of effort to cross verify duplicate rows and eyeball every column.

Is there any way to restrict the Qualtrics generic link survey respondents to take only one ?

or

Is there any why we can save the USER-ID and USER_REF_NO field values in sql server database once Qualtrics survey is submitted ? So that we can restrict Qualtric generic link display on web page by checking existence of user from database table.

I have tried with Qualtrics Prevent ballot-box stuffing feature. but, its limiting all users who are using same browser. This is not the solution for my problem. I have searched online but I could not' find anything related to this specific requirement.

I know there is an option with Qualtrics API web-service, but for this we have to buy license. Due to some reasons we are looking to achieve this by any other alternatives.

Qualtrics experts please share your advise or any material/links/reference materiel would be helpful.

**Update:**

As suggested by T. Gibbons, I have created webservice which receives two input parameters and saves them in database table. I'm  working on test server and moved the webservice code to the test server.

Please find the below images
[image]
[image]

Please find the qualtrics external web service call, I have added the web-service block after the main survey body block.

[image]

**Questions:**
1. I have copied the web service to the test server, now do I need to host this web service in our test IIS server as an application or can I leave just like this ? 
2. After submitting the Qualtrics survey, ID and Reference numbers are not inserting into the database table, I couldn't able to find the problem in Qualtrics web service call.
3. Is the alignment of the Web-service block is correct in the Qualtrics interface or do I need to change it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a web service call just before end of survey to save the USER-ID and USER_REF_NO to a SQL database. For responses that have completed previously, you can download them from Qualtrics and import them into your database.

Then, you can add a web service call to the beginning of your survey that checks if the USER-ID and USER_REF_NO are already in the database, and if they are you can terminate and screen-out the survey response immediately.

Comment: Can we call external  web-service from Qualtrics tool after submitting the survey to save USER_ID and USER_REF_No to SQL database? We can't save USER_ID before end of the survey as user may leave without hitting the submit right. Our users list is dynamic so we can't maintain manually and download them from Qualtrics to import into database. Can you share me any reference url for this please.

Comment: You can add the web service call after your last question block and before the end of survey block. The web service IS what saves the USER_ID and USER_REF_NO to the SQL database. I don't understand your second point, you said you wanted to prevent the same USER_ID and USER_REF_NO from taking the survey again. Downloading previous responses and importing those fields into your database would do that. https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-flow/advanced-elements/web-service/

Comment: @t-gibbons , thanks for the suggestion, I'm working on the external web-service call,  I have updated the post. Could you please look at the 'Update' part. Thanks.

Comment: You need to "pipe" the parameters into the web service: ${m://ExternalDataReference} and ${e://Field/PIDM}.

Comment: Also, since you are doing a POST, I think your input fields should be under "Add a body parameter..." instead of "Query Parameters".  Until recently all Web Services were GET, so I haven't use POST yet.